# Full Link Extraction using java

Tags: java

My goal is to always get the same string (which is the URI in my case) while reading the href property from a link. Example:
Suppose think that a html file it have somany links like
`a href="index.html">` but base domain is http://www.domainname.com/index.html
`a href="../index.html">` but base domain is http://www.domainname.com/dit/index.html
how can i get all the link correctly means the full link including domain name? 

how can i do that in java?

 the input is HTML,that is,from a bunch of HTML code it need to extract correct link

Comment: You you have access to the Request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using a fullworthy HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). There's a [`Node#absUrl()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29) which does exactly what you want.

```
package com.stackoverflow.q3394298;

import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394298/");
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element link = document.select("a.question-hyperlink").first();
        System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
        System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
    }
    
}
```

which prints (correctly) the following for the title link of your current question:

```
/questions/3394298/full-link-extraction-using-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394298/full-link-extraction-using-java
```

Jsoup may have more other (undiscovered) advantages for your purpose as well.

#### Related questions:

- [What are the pros and cons of the leading HTML parsers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers)

---

**Update**: if you want to select *all* links in the document, then do as follows:

```
        Elements links = document.select("a");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println(link.absUrl("href"));
        }
```

Comment: Can you gave me a full code, i am not that much master in JAVA,will you please help?

Comment: OK, I edited it into a SSCCE flavor so that you can copy'n'paste'n'run it without changes (you just need to drop Jsoup JAR file in classpath).

Comment: its shows an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Test.main<Test.java:13>" I gave site http://www.yahoo.com and shows the above error

Comment: You need to select the link(s) of interest. The `"a.question-hyperlink"` basically selects all `<a>` elements which have a `class="question-hyperlink"`. Rightclick page and view source. Here at stackoverflow.com there is one such link. At yahoo.com they don't have them. You need to alter the selector to select exactly those element(s) of interest. If you want to select all links, then use `document.select("a")` and loop over the obtained links. This has been answered in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386065).

Comment: See my answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383152/how-to-find-hyperlink-in-a-webpage-using-java.

Answer (score 3):

Use the URL object:

URL url = new URL(URL context, String spec)

Here's an example:

import java.net.*;

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   URL base = new URL("http://www.java.com/dit/index.html");   
   URL url = new URL(base, "../hello.html");

   System.out.println(base);
   System.out.println(url);
}
}
```

It will print:

```
http://www.java.com/dit/index.html
http://www.java.com/hello.html
```

Comment: it will not extract link from a URL,because for me, the input is HTML,that is,from a bunch of HTML code it need to extract correct link

Comment: @Alex Mathew, Untrue, you can combine the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383152/how-to-find-hyperlink-in-a-webpage-using-java with this answer to do exactly what you intend to do. Pleass put some effort into it. And my guess is that both these questions are for the same problem